# using model prediction inside another model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How can one use model.predict inside another model? I need to add a layer at the end of model that uses predictions form another model.

I get this error:

```
ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 10)
```

when trying the following:

```
... 
model1_outputs = model1.predict(model1_inputs)

model2 = Model(inputs=model2_inputs, outputs=model1_outputs)
```

Comment: I think I found it, I am using this instead:

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, I am using this instead:

```
model1_outputs = model1(model1_inputs)

model2 = Model(inputs=model2_inputs, outputs=model1_outputs)
```